# Circular ProgressBar Animation

Tags: animation, adobe-flash, mask, adobe-after-effects

I want to create a simple circular progress animation with either Adobe After Effect or Adobe Flash or any other software that you may suggest. Something like this:

[image: ProgrssBar]

Assuming that the graphic assets are available and I only want the filling animation. I guess that I need some masking technique to create the filling motion. But I have no idea how to create a growing circular mask. If it was a horizontal progress, I would only need to resize the mask to reveal the underlying layer gradually. But what about this? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Couple code examples come to mind: http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html and http://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/ ( working example: http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/BHEwo )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a pinch, After Effects has a transition effect called "Clock Wipe"… !

Comment: Yep—hopefully these images will help!

http://cl.ly/image/2G3r2Z221t3N/Screen%20Shot%202014-05-10%20at%201.01.20%20PM.png
http://cl.ly/image/1S1D1U3J1d13/Screen%20Shot%202014-05-10%20at%201.01.26%20PM.png
http://cl.ly/image/153F291A2d3c/Screen%20Shot%202014-05-10%20at%201.02.04%20PM.png

Answer (score 2):

You can draw arbitrary shapes using Flash's [**Graphics**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) class. That said, it sounds like you just need the final animation, so this is probably overkill, but if you drop this code on the timeline it will draw a pie style progress mask. You can edit the size (and increase the segments if it looks rough) using the consts.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.GraphicsPath;
import flash.events.Event;

const INNER_RADIUS:Number = 50;
const OUTER_RADIUS:Number = 70;
const SEGMENTS_PER_RADIAN:uint = 10;

var maskGraphic:Sprite = new Sprite();
maskGraphic.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5;
maskGraphic.y = stage.stageHeight * 0.5;
addChild(maskGraphic);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, tick);
var percentage:Number = 0;
function tick(e:Event):void {
    percentage += 0.5;
    drawProgress(percentage);
}

function drawProgress(percentage:Number):void {
    percentage = percentage > 100? percentage % 100 : percentage;

    maskGraphic.graphics.clear();
    maskGraphic.graphics.beginFill(0xFF00FF, 1.0);

    var outerEdge:GraphicsPath = new GraphicsPath();
    var innerEdge:GraphicsPath = new GraphicsPath();

    var radians:Number = percentage * 0.01 * Math.PI * 2;
    var divisions:uint = Math.round(radians * SEGMENTS_PER_RADIAN);
    var ang:Number;
    for (var i:uint = 0; i <= divisions; i++) {
        ang = i / divisions * radians;
        outerEdge.lineTo(Math.sin(ang) * OUTER_RADIUS, -Math.cos(ang) * OUTER_RADIUS);
        ang = (divisions - i) / divisions * radians;
        innerEdge.lineTo(Math.sin(ang) * INNER_RADIUS, -Math.cos(ang) * INNER_RADIUS);
    }
    maskGraphic.graphics.moveTo(Math.sin(0) * OUTER_RADIUS, -Math.cos(0) * OUTER_RADIUS);
    maskGraphic.graphics.drawPath(outerEdge.commands.concat(innerEdge.commands), outerEdge.data.concat(innerEdge.data));
}
```

Comment: This is cool David, and thanks for your contribution. I'll try it and report back.